# Stopping independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, stopping-times, optimal-control

Let $\{X_n\}$ be independent (and identically distributed if necessary) integrable random variables. Consider the stopping time, adapted to the natural filtration as usual, $\tau$ (that is $\{\tau=n\}\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Denote the class of stopping times that do not stop before $n$ as $T_n=\{\tau\:\text{stopping time}: \tau\geq n\}$.

Is it true that, as intuitively seems reasonable, for all $n$, $\operatorname{ess\, sup} \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n}X_\tau=\sup \mathbb{E}X_\tau$ for the essential supremum and supremum running over all $\tau\in T_{n+1}$? If not, can we show at least that they are deterministic numbers $v_n=\operatorname{ess\, sup} \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n}X_\tau$?

The intuition comes from the following reasoning: since $\tau$ does not stop by time $n$, the information given by the history is irrelevant for the future reward. However I cannot formalise this quite well, since the random variables $\mathbb{1}_{\tau=i}$ for all $i\geq n+1$ involved in the conditional expectation above are, I believe, not necessarily independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$, they are only, as far as I know, only $\mathcal{F}_i$-measurable, and although $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}\subset\ldots$, I do not think this translates directly into independence, just because $\mathcal{F}_{n+1}=\sigma(\mathcal{F}_n,\sigma(X_{n+1}))$ and $\sigma(X_{n+1})$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_n$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem with your argument is that $\tau$, as you noted yourself, does not need to be independent of $\mathcal F_n$! Indeed, consider $\tau := n + 1 + \lfloor X_1\rfloor$. Then $\tau \geq n+1$ but still does on $X_1$. The following examples makes this more explicit: $X_1$ a Bernoulli(1/2) variable, $X_{n+1} = 0$ and $X_{n+2} = 1$. The others are irrelevant and can be taken to be some independent variables. Then $\mathbb E X_\tau = 1/2$, but $\mathbb E[X_\tau \vert \mathcal F_n] = 1_{X_1 = 1}$.

Comment: Apologies there is a typo in the question, outside expectation there is an essential supremum. Your example is correct and is the type of things I had in mind for the last paragraph.

Comment: Your comment also made me think that perhaps the results holds only for iid, so I also added that in case independence is not enough.

Comment: what do you mean by esssup? On the left, I can understand. But on the right? That should just be a deterministic number, no?

Comment: yes on fhe right it reduces to the regular sup

Comment: I am also interested, to get to understand the problem, in the slightly weaker version of it, that is if the $esssup \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n}X_\tau$ are deterministic numbers $v_n$.

Comment: Regular sup? Over **what** are you taking the supremum?

Comment: I wrote it in words after the formula for ease of reading, over all stopping rules that do not stop by $n$.

Comment: These suprema and essential suprema formalise the notion of future rewards for stopping rules that have gotten to step $n$ essentially. The question is if under independence, the future reward becomes deterministic in the stage number.

Comment: The confusion is that ess sup normally refers to a supremum over $\omega$, i.e. the largest possible value of a single random variable mod null sets.  But $\mathbb{E} X_\tau$ isn't a random variable, it is a number (for each $\tau$).  Esssup doesn't "reduce" to regular sup, it just doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean to claim is that $$\sup_{\tau \in T_n} \operatorname{esssup} \mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n} X_\tau = \sup_{\tau \in T_n} \mathbb{E} X_\tau$$

Comment: @NateEldredge No, the future reward is defined as $esssup_{\tau\in T_n}$ when dealing with random variables. I mean to prove either that $esssup_{\tau\in T_n}\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n}X_\tau= \sup_{\tau\in T_n}\mathbb{E} X_\tau$ or, if this is not the case, the perhaps weaker statement that $v_n = esssup_{\tau\in T_n}\mathbb{E}_{\mathcal{F}_n}X_\tau$ are not random. In general all equalitites are meant to hold almost surely.

Comment: @NateEldredge I edited the second $esssup$ into regular $sup$ for clarity, although I believe in this case it does reduces to a $sup$ anyway: the smallest possible random variable upperbounding a deterministic set of values almost surely can only be the supremum of that set of values, otherwise we would have a contradiction (use the property of the essential supremum admitting a countable set converging to the regular supremum).

Comment: Ok the above discussion clarifies the question a bit. Please write \sup_{\tau\in T_{n+1}} to make it clear in the question. The problem with the esssup remains, as pointed out by @NateEldredge. Indeed, the essential supremum is always w.r.t. some measure. But what measure do you want to put on the set of stopping times? I think that you may be misunderstanding this notion. That needs clarification before being able to answer the question...

Comment: @MushuNrek The essential supremum is well defined over any set of objects, with repsect to which you decide to index the argument. These object do not have to be numbers, even though the standard def of esssup, usually given in analysis, tend to use them. Here, as the set of our object to use as indices, we take the class of stopping rules (which may be uncountable, hence the necessity of using esssup and not sup, to keep the final object measurable) that do not stop before n (if n=0, you get all the stopping rules, but then also the expectation is unconditional and there is nothing to prove).

Comment: @GGG Could you state a **rigorous** definition of what you mean by esssup?

Comment: @MushuNrek It is essentially the same as the sup, but modulo negligible events: For a collection of random variables $\{X_t\}_{t\in T}$, we say that a random variable $Z=esssup X_t$ is a) $Z\geq X_t$ a.s. for every $t\in T$ b) if another random variable $Z'$ is such that $Z'\geq X_t$ a.s. for every $t\in T$, then $Z'\geq Z$ a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the $X_n$ are iid and that there exists $C\in\Bbb R$ such that $P[X_1\le C]=1$.(The situation in which $P[X_1 >C]>0$ for all real $C$ is treated in a similar fashion.)

Fix $n$. Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $B=[C-\epsilon,C]$. Then $P[X_k\in B]>0$ (and doesn't depend on $k$) and so the stopping time
$$
\tau:=\inf\{k\ge n+1: X_k\in B\}
$$
is a.s. finite and an element of $T_n$. Clearly $\Bbb E[X_\tau]\ge C-\epsilon$. It follows that $\sup_{\tau\in T_n}\Bbb E[X_\tau]=C$.

On the other hand $\Bbb E_{\mathcal F_n}[X_\tau]\le C$ a.s. because $\Bbb P[X_k\le C,\forall k]=1$. In the reverse direction fix $n$ and define $\tau$ as before. Notice that $\tau$ and (more importantly) $X_\tau$ are independent of $\mathcal F_n$. Therefore $\Bbb E_{\mathcal F_n}[X_\tau]=\Bbb E[X_\tau]\ge C-\epsilon$, a.s.. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{ess\, sup}_{\tau\in T_n}\Bbb E_{\mathcal F_n}[X_\tau]=\sup_{\tau\in T_n}\Bbb E[X_\tau]=C,
$$
for all $n$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, it seems your assumption is stronger than boundedness of $X$: I think you are both assuming boundedness and that the distribution has mass at the least upper bound $C$. In the discrete case this would be a mass precisely at $C$, in the continuous case it would be also following from the property of the least upper bound, but I am not sure for more general distributions (e.g. singular ones) so there may be more loss of generality here.

Comment: I've written the details for $X_1$ bounded above. And $C$ should have been chosen to be the essential supremum of $X_1$—thanks for noticing that error.

Comment: I see, of course then if $C$ is essential supremum I agree that we should have some mass there, even with $\epsilon$ arbitrary, which was my concern. I will read again the argument carefully.

Comment: Everything is correct now, I wonder, do you think the iid hypothesis can be dropped? We use it essentially to guarantee almost sure finiteness of the stopping time. Without it though, this proof seems to require quantitative bounds on $\mathbb{P}(X_k\in B)$ ($C$ would have to be a uniform essential bound on the $\{X_k\}$ assumed e.g. with common support). I am starting to think that identical distributions are actually an essential requirement here... if $\tau$ where allowed infinite, which could be a possibility, $\mathbb{E}X_\tau\geq C-\epsilon$ would not necessarily hold.

Answer (score 1):

When $X_1$ is essentially unbounded above,  given any real  $L$ we have  $\Bbb P[X_1\ge L]>0$. Now define $\tau:=\inf\{k\ge n+1: X_k \ge L\}$. Then $\tau$ is a.s. finite and $\Bbb E[X_\tau]\ge L$. It follows that $\sup_{\tau\in T_n}\Bbb E[X_\tau]=+\infty$. Because the $\tau$ just constructed is independent of $\mathcal F_n$, we even have  $\Bbb E_{\mathcal F_n}[X_\tau]\ge L$, so the reverse inequality follows as before.